# Overlay of blocks in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have several `blocks` in a slide:

```
\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}
\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}
\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}
```

Does anyone know how to overlay them so as to show them block by block by left-clicking mouse?

Comment: `\pause` between blocks maybe? Or do want them on top of each other? Your question is not very specific to that regard.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Three ways (depending on how you want them to appear, there might be other possibilities):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\onslide<+->{\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}}
\onslide<+->{\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}}
\onslide<+->{\begin{block}{block 3}
  block 3
\end{block}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\only<1>{\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}}
\only<2>{\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}}
\only<3>{\begin{block}{block 3}
  block 3
\end{block}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 3}
  block 3
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between the 1st and the 3rd solutions?

Comment: @SoftTimur `\pause` and `\onslide` behave differently when used inside environments (in my little example there will be no difference since the commands were not used inside environments). The `beamer` documentation contains the details.

Comment: I found Solution 2 to be the best substitute for block transition animations. It has a lot of use cases while preparing slides. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is also a shorter version which makes use of beamer block being overlay aware: `\begin{block}<only@1>{title}`...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}<only@1->{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}
\begin{block}<2->{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}
\begin{block}<3->{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}

\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255860)

Comment: @Miyase Why does this not answer the question? Sure, a small test document would be nice, but beamer blocks are overlay aware so this is a convenient approach to animate their appearance.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz When I posted this, there was no MWE, only a very curt answer that required additional explanations. I see that the content of the answer has changed since then.